# RabbitMQ cannot publish message using management plugin on windows server 2008 R2

Tags: rabbitmq, windows-server-2008-r2

I need to publish some test messages using the management UI.

I can see the "Publish message" at the "Queues" section on my windows 7 machine but not on the windows server 2008 R2.

I have installed the RabbitMQ the same way on both machines.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can check the version in the overview section of the management UI, just make sure they are exactly the same version first.

Comment: also check that you have permissions to that queue.

Comment: It is very weird. I can do it when I go to that page on my machine (by  IP) but not when I logged into it. Anyway, I am able to publish message this way now. Thanks guys!